# Issue with css form in Rails app

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, railstutorial.org

I'm learning railstutorial.org and recently decided to create my own blog. I did it and now it looks like 
[image: this]
Problem is about articles, text into them is in one line and I don't understand why

My custom.css.scss file:

```
@import "bootstrap";

/* universal */

$grayMediumLight: #eaeaea;

html {
overflow-y: scroll;
}

 body {
padding-top: 60px;
}

section {
overflow: auto;
}

textarea {
resize: both;
}

 .center    {
text-align: center;
h1 {
margin-bottom: 10px;
}
}

 p {
text-align: left;
}
```

P.S. I aspire to 
[image: this]

Comment: You should try adding spaces to your fake content.

Answer (score 0):

It is due to the overflow you have added to section and html. Remove these and then see what you have. Also set a width of `400px` to the container that houses the blog posts.

Comment: I removed html and section. Nothing happened

Comment: To be of any more help i'd need a link to the site or the problem recreated in a fiddle

Comment: Sorry for delay. Is github suitable for you? [link](https://github.com/drigzzz/blog)